# How to specify the platform when generating POMs with Tycho?

Tags: maven, tycho

My company has been building their Eclipse RCP Application with Ant as a PDE-build. I'm trying to migrate the build process to Tycho but I am getting several errors of the same kind. I only want to build for Windows 64-bit but Tycho keeps looking for Cocoa plugins, which are marked as optional in the features.

How can I tell Tycho not to bother about anything that is not related to Windows 64 bit?

The manifest files do already exist, and I tried to generate the POMs with:

```
mvn org.eclipse.tycho:maven-tycho-plugin:generate-poms -Dtycho.targetPlatform=<path to target> -DgroupId=myGroupId
```

The error I get is:

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve plugin org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.cocoa_0.11.0.v20120716-173435;
```

I'm using Java 1.7.0_11, Maven 3.1.0, and Tycho 0.18.1.

Comment: Any particular reason that you are using the ancient 0.11.1 version? The [currently latest release](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes) is 0.18.0.

Comment: current tycho release is 0.18.1 (esp. if you want to use it with maven 3.1.x). See http://eclipse.org/tycho

Comment: I used the deprecated sonatype repository, where 0.11.1 was the newest version. After switching to org.eclipse.tycho and Tycho 0.18.1 I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to set the platform in the **target-platform-configuration** plugin configuration as follows:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <environments>
        <environment>
          <os>win32</os>
          <ws>win32</ws>
          <arch>x86_64</arch>
        </environment>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Do you mean in the master pom? The command that fails is the generate poms. I only have the manifest files and about 1000 plugins so I can't just set up a master pom by hand.

Comment: Ah, OK. I see your problem now. Sorry, I don't see how to solve this. I only have a vague recollection of generate-poms, and it's not a happy memory.